# How do I remove duplicate cmake targets created by sub-cmake targets?

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project that depends on several other cmake projects.
The cmake project that I am writing depends on 2 cmake projects that both create `uninstall` targets.
These duplicate targets cause errors:

```sh
add_custom_target cannot create target "uninstall" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory
```

I do not need the `uninstall` target from either sub-cmake project. How do I exclude all targets with the name `uninstall` so that I don't get these errors? What other options are there available to solve this error? I am looking for a solution that is OS agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I sugguest you read the following documentation for Kitware : https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#can-i-do-make-uninstall-with-cmake .
The process is quite well explained.

Comment: Answers on SO should consist of more than just a link.